# Ionic White screen on project that only contains sidemenu template

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Ionic Info
Ionic:

```
ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.7.5
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 0.7.5
@angular/cli                  : 6.2.4
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.0.0
```

Cordova:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.1, browser 5.0.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.0, (and 4 other plugins)
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/we/Library//Android/sdk)
   NodeJS            : v8.11.4 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode             : Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a
```

I created a new Project with the Following command:

```
ionic start sandbox2 sidemenu --type=angular
```

then i tried to deploy it to an android device using this command:

```
ionic cordova emulate android --target="nexus"
```

the target was an Emulator with Android 7 (API 24)
I didn't change any of the code but the only thing i saw was a white screen.

Console output:

```
    The key "viewport-fit" is not recognized and ignored.
vendor.js:34241Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
    vendor.js:32793ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object.values is not a function(…)defaultErrorLogger @ vendor.js:32793
    vendor.js:32793ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: containerEl.commit is not a function(…)defaultErrorLogger @ vendor.js:32793
    vendor.js:64239Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 995 ms
```

Because of the white Screen i expected the DOM to show an empty app-root Tag but i found this:

```
<body>
    <app-root ng-version="6.1.9">
        <ion-app>
            <ion-split-pane>
                <ion-menu>
                    <ion-header>
                        <ion-toolbar>
                            <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
                        </ion-toolbar>
                    </ion-header>
                    <ion-content>
                        <ion-list>
                            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}-->
                            <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false">
                                <ion-item tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-direction="root" ng-reflect-router-link="/home">
                                    <ion-icon slot="start" ng-reflect-name="home"></ion-icon>
                                    <ion-label> Home </ion-label>
                                </ion-item>
                            </ion-menu-toggle>
                            <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false">
                                <ion-item tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-direction="root" ng-reflect-router-link="/list">
                                    <ion-icon slot="start" ng-reflect-name="list"></ion-icon>
                                    <ion-label> List </ion-label>
                                </ion-item>
                            </ion-menu-toggle>
                        </ion-list>
                    </ion-content>
                </ion-menu>
                <ion-router-outlet main="">
                    <app-home _nghost-c0="" class="ion-page ion-page-invisible">
                        <ion-header _ngcontent-c0="">
                            <ion-toolbar _ngcontent-c0="">
                                <ion-buttons _ngcontent-c0="" slot="start">
                                    <ion-menu-button _ngcontent-c0=""></ion-menu-button>
                                </ion-buttons>
                                <ion-title _ngcontent-c0=""> Home </ion-title>
                            </ion-toolbar>
                        </ion-header>
                        <ion-content _ngcontent-c0="" padding=""> The world is your oyster.
                            <p _ngcontent-c0="">If you get lost, the <a _ngcontent-c0="" href="https://ionicframework.com/docs" rel="noopener" target="_blank">docs</a> will be your guide.</p>
                        </ion-content>
                    </app-home>
                </ion-router-outlet>
            </ion-split-pane>
        </ion-app>
    </app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</body>
```

I don't know why the Styles are missing to show the sidemenu Template that i added to this project.

When i tried to deploy the project to a Browser it worked perfectly fine. I used this command for that:

```
ionic cordova run browser
```

I already tried to change the `<base href="/" />` to `<base href="." />` without success.

The next thing i did was to remove the ion-page-invisible style on the home page like that:

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private el: ElementRef
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

   this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'ion-page-invisible');
  }
}
```

i checked that on my android device and the style was removed....but i still see nothing.

**UPDATE**

I have now tested it on Android and IOS Emulator, didn't work, but then i tried my physical Device and got it working, it is a Problem with the API Level.

Working:
API 26 Oreo (Android 8.0) -> Tried it in emulator after physical device, both worked
Mac nativ
Browser

Not Working:
Android API 25 and below
Iphone Simulator with IOS 10 -> not working

Didn't get to work because of other errors:
Android API over 26 because of "PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU "